# The drush command 'rets-import' could not be found

Tags: drush

I believe I have all the pieces of the Drupal RETS Real Estate Framework installed in my drupal 7 site.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drealty

But when I run:

```
drush -u=admin -d rets-import
```

I get:

```
The drush command 'rets-import' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.
```

What step might I have missed in my install of this framework?

Comment: Have you run that commnand form a directory inside your Drupal installation? Have you run the drush cache-clear drush command? Is he module enabled?

Comment: Yes, to all 3 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file that integrates DRealty with Drush `drealty.drush.inc` is kind of in an odd place within a `drush` folder of the module.

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drealty/tree/drush/drealty.drush.inc

Drush will scan the root level of a module folder or your `.drush` directory for drush include files but I dont think it will randomly scan deeply into module directories. I recommend moving this file into your `.drush` folder and clearing the cache, then trying from your site folder again. Eg,

- cp ./drealty/drush/drealty.drush.inc ~/.drush
- drush cc drush
- cd YOUR_DRUPAL_PROJECT/sites/all/modules
- drush -u=admin -d rets-import

Comment: This worked thank you very much!   Is this a bug in DRealty module that should be reported?

Comment: it's not a bug persay. Drush support is optional. Drush's scanning behavior is documented within drush .... if anything it could use a mention in their `README.txt` or `INSTALL.txt`. If you want to open an issue for them on the matter it probably wouldn't be a bad idea.